# How to use multiple checkbox and a submit button to retrieve firebase realtime database data

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve specific data from firebase. Example, specific actor from database if the submitted checkbox id is matched with genre of an actor

Answer (score 0):

You can use `orderByChild`

```
List<string> actors = new ArrayList<>();

   foreach(String actor: actors){

   ref.orderByChild(actor).addListenerforSingleValueEvent
   //continue the listener
   }
```

This how you add an actor to `List`

```
if(checkBox.Check()){
   actors.Add(actorName);
}else{
    actors.Remove(actorName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First check which all `checkboxes` are checked, for that on the button click check all the `checkboxes` ie., `checkbox.isChecked();`
If checked add the name of the actor to the query.

Comment: May i have an example on how to add the name to the query if a specific checkbox is checked?